# search for a string in all database

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is any stored procedure, or query which search in all database (that means also others procedures) for a specific string?

I want to search all stored procedures' code for the word `Raiserror`, and I have only the string to resolve the cause of that raiserror.

Thank u

Answer (score 3):

I use RedGate SQL Search to find text in stored procedures. It's free and installs into Management Studio.

Answer (score 2):

This will find stored procedures, views, functions, and triggers containing your text...

```
    DECLARE @SearchString nvarchar(max)
    SET @SearchString = 'Raiserror' --Text You Want To Find

    SELECT DISTINCT
        [SysObjects].[name] AS [Object Name],
        [SysObjects].[type_desc] AS [Object Type]
    FROM 
        [sys].[sql_modules] AS [SysMods]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [sys].[objects] AS [SysObjects] ON [SysMods].[object_id] = [SysObjects].[object_id]
    WHERE 
        [SysMods].[definition] LIKE '%' + @SearchString + '%'
    /*
        --comment this in to only fined stored procedures
        AND
        [SysObjects].[type_desc] = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
    */
    ORDER BY 
        [SysObjects].[type_desc] ASC,
        [SysObjects].[name] ASC
```